# Kernel of group epimorphism with finitely presented is the normal closure of a finite subset .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-property, combinatorial-group-theory

> Suppose $F : G \rightarrow K $ is a group epimorphism with $G$ finitely generated and $K$ finitely presented. Then, show that $H := \ker F$ is the normal closure of a finite subset in $H$.

### My attempt

Since $F$ is surjective, so $G/H \cong K$, say $\varphi : G/H \rightarrow K $.

So, I think since $K$ has a finite relation set $R_K$, $R_k$ is the key point..

However, I don't have any idea. How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean $G/H\cong K$.

Comment: thank you, i edit it!

Comment: For each generaror $k_i$ of $K$, let $g_i$ be any inverse image of $k_i$ under $F$. The defining relators of $K$ are words $w_j$  in $k_i$ and $k_i^{-1}$. Let $v_j$ be the elements of $G$ defined by the same words evaluated in $g_i$ and $g_i^{-1}$. Then you can take $H$ to be the set of these elements $v_j$.